# UTC time stamp to Datetime in Sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

can any one help me to create a function which gives me Datetime value if I pass UTC time stamp in milliseconds in SQL server?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using? mysql or sql server?

Comment: What is the epoch base time for the UTC milliseconds? What Microsoft SQL Server version?

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your issue, if none of the answers solved the issue you should write your own answer instead of writing this Thanks words. For more information about accepting answers you can read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/Tour)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get UTC to local datetime format:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), MyTable.UtcColumn) 
   AS ColumnInLocalTime
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to create a function for this in SQL SERVER, then your query should be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UTCtoLocal(@UTC datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @local datetime
DECLARE @datediff INT = (select DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()))

SET @local = DATEADD(mi, @datediff, @UTC)

RETURN @local

END
GO
```

Then You can pass the utc time as a parameter and get the local time

```
SELECT [dbo].[UTCtoLocal] (GETUTCDATE())
```